# How to get the best price when purchasing large amounts of household goods in the US?

Tags: usa, relocation, shopping

When moving to the US and outfitting a house with linens, kitchen stuff, and small appliances one can easily spend a couple thousand dollars in a single store like Target or Bed Bath and Beyond. How do you find out if a store gives a "bulk" discount?

Comment: You just ask them if they do.  Most don't.

Comment: @karlson that is what I did. Target gives 5% off if you use their credit card, Bed Bath and Beyond gives 20% off for new movers. Going shop to shop and trying to find the right person who understands what you want seems inefficient.

Comment: Yes it is.  The thing is that these discounts aren't being advertised and 5% off isn't limited to the large purchase at move time.

Comment: Answer: Visit the Salvation Army store or Goodwill.